# Ошибка: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '('

Tags: php

Скрипт не отрабатывает, а матерится на ф-ю.

> Ошибка: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '('

До него все скобки закрыты, знаки проставлены.

Проблемный кусок кода:

Строки с 39 по 45

```
function load_stat(){
    $load_stati = file_get_contents($url);
    if ($load_stati == "Auth error!"){
        die("Не верные ID или auth_key");
    }else{
    echo $load_stati;
    }
}
```

Comment: вы выложили явно не тот кусок кода. Этот работает

Comment: ругается на это, вот и пытаюсь понять, в чем дело.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2WwF6jDd

весь код

Comment: даже если это всё убрать - то же самое

Comment: после имени функции забыл () написать. закрывайте

Answer (score 1):

У вас там лишняя закрывающая фигурная скобка как минимум. Плюс ошибка в этой строке: `$id = strip_tags(id);`

P.S. Смените редактор, нормальный ошибки в скобках сразу покажет.

Answer (score 1):

[@Lalka](/users/20028/lalka), еще ошибка вот тут:

```
$parsexml = $dom -> getElementByTagName('param');
echo $pasrexml; # должно быть $parsexml
```

Answer (score 1):

> > > $dom -> getElementByTagName('param');

Должно быть `$dom->getElementsByTagName('param');`